# How to ignore a case in awk?

Tags: parsing, awk

Hi I am trying to make my awk script ignore all lines of the input file who have in `rw=none` in it but all other `rw=*` should still be matched.

I have tried with this code, but it does not work out because I do not ignore the whole line if the string is matching

My attempt:

```
match($0,/(rw=[^,]*)/){
    !/rw=none/
    n=split(substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3),N,/:/)
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)print '$NETAPP_ID', vFiler, $1, N[i];
}
```

Example output:

```
/vol/lnxpeayh   -sec=sys,rw=none
/vol/lnxplmulhall   -sec=sys,rw=172.17.10.78:sfilerp01.os.net
```

wished Output is:

```
/vol/lnxplmulhall 172.17.10.78
/vol/lnxplmulhall sfilerp01.os.net
```

The code should ignore every line which has `rw=none` in it, just ignoring the string is not enough

Comment: `IGNORECASE` is to ignore the upper/lowercase. Provide some sample input and desired output.

Comment: try putting IGNORECASE in BEGIN block

Comment: edited it with a example

Comment: @ghostdog74 putting IGNORECASE in a BEGIN block does somehow give me no output back

Comment: This is why you should always read the man page.Try `!/rw=none/`. Also what actual output do you want because i think you may be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: !/rw=none/ does still give me back the rw=none line, added output

Comment: Why have you still got IGNORECASE. Fedorqui clearly explains what it does in the first comment. Do you actually have any idea what any of the code you posted does, or have you just copied it and stuck IGNORECASE in and hoped for the best ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to edit the code above ...

Comment: well I just realized that it has to ignore the whole line if there is rw=none in it, just ignoring the string is not enough with the code I have

Comment: It doesn't just ignore the string,it does nothing where you have put it, you clearly have no idea how awk works at all. Read the man page for it and then show a new attempt.

Comment: I have read the man page and yes it is true that i do not have that much of an idea how it works becaue I started using it 2 days ago ... I thought it would be better to show you how i think it would work which in my mind is better than just going into this and basically saying "I did not try anything, can you please solve my problem so I do not have to think?" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/rw=none/ {next}
match($0, /rw=([^,]*)/, m) {
    n = split(m[1], N, /:/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print '$NETAPP_ID', vFiler, $1, N[i];
}
```

Notice how I changed the parentheses in the `match` regex? Now you don't need the substr function to extract the `rw` value.